# Negative lookahead for hyphen

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have the following line "Orig. 750-52.00 and orig. 3.99" and I want to extract orig. 3.99 from this line.
I am trying to do so using the following code

```
s = "Orig. 750-52.00 and orig. 3.99"
orig = re.compile(r"(orig.\s?[\d|\.]+)(?!-)", re.IGNORECASE)
if orig.search(s):
    print "Yes:", orig.search(s).groups()
```

Output: Yes: ('Orig. 75',)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add the digit pattern into the negative lookahead pattern to disallow backtracking to yield an incomplete number match:

```
orig\.\s*\d[\d.]*(?!-|\.?\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c5kJ8X/3).

**Details**

- `orig\.` - an `orig.` substring (note that the dot must be escaped to match a literal dot)
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\d[\d.]*` - a digit followed with 0+ digits or `.` chars
- `(?!-|\.?\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a hyphen or an optional `.` followed with a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JdukcQ):

```
import re
s = "Orig. 750-52.00 and orig. 3.99"
orig = re.compile(r"orig\.\s*\d[\d.]*(?!-|\.?\d)", re.IGNORECASE)
m = orig.search(s)
if m:
    print("Yes: {}".format(m.group()))
# => Yes: orig. 3.99
```

Also, note that it is not necessary to repeat the `orig.search(s)` search operation, you can assign the regex search result to a variable (see `m`) and then, after checking if the match data object is not `None`, access the whole match via `m.group()`.

Comment: @RupjitChakraborty Just FYI: `[\d|\.]` matches a digit, `.` or `|` since `|` inside a character class is parsed as a literal pipe char, you need to remove it. `\d[\d.]*` is better than `[\d.]+` because that prevents dot only chunks from matching (e.g. in `orig.......`)

Comment: Thanks for that. However the regex is failing for "Orig. 6.99-799.99 and orig. 3.99".

Comment: @RupjitChakraborty There is a quick and dirty way to also avoid matching that first number using [`orig\.\s*\d[\d.]*(?![\d.-])`](https://regex101.com/r/c5kJ8X/1). However, I think `orig\.\s*\d[\d.]*(?!-|\.?\d)` will be a more precise pattern here.